# Log read, write and error counts with Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a Sprint batch with the job as

```
<batch:job id="data-send" parent="baseJob">
    <batch:listeners merge="true">
        <batch:listener ref="someJobExecutionListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
    <batch:step id="data-send.step01">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobTransactionManager" ref="dataSendTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The tasklet pseudo code is

```
@Component
public class DataSendTasklet implements Tasklet {
 
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute((final StepContribution contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

   List<SomeObject> objectList = dbGetOperation();
   objectList.stream().forEach(o -> someDataSendOperation(o));
   log("ReadCount: "+objectList.size());
   return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Currently, I am logging the read count by calculating the objectList's size and If I had to log the processed records and error records I would have to keep track of a variable inside the someDataSendOperation method. Is there any Spring off-the-shelf functionality to handle the read, write and error counts in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case, I created a StepListener and print all the useful information. Here is the example:

```
public class StepExecuteListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StepExecuteListener.class);

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // No action needed
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getCommitCount= {}", stepExecution.getCommitCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getFilterCount= {}", stepExecution.getFilterCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getProcessSkipCount= {}", stepExecution.getProcessSkipCount());
    LOG.info("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getReadCount= {}", stepExecution.getReadCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getReadSkipCount= {}", stepExecution.getReadSkipCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getRollbackCount= {}", stepExecution.getRollbackCount());
    LOG.info("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getWriteCount= {}", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getWriteSkipCount= {}", stepExecution.getWriteSkipCount());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getStepName= {}", stepExecution.getStepName());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getSummary= {}", stepExecution.getSummary());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getStartTime= {}", stepExecution.getStartTime());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getStartTime= {}", stepExecution.getEndTime());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getLastUpdated= {}", stepExecution.getLastUpdated());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getExitStatus= {}", stepExecution.getExitStatus());
    LOG.debug("StepExecutionListener - afterStep:getFailureExceptions= {}", stepExecution.getFailureExceptions());
   
    
    return null;
}
   }
```

Comment: Hi, since in my use case I don't have a reader or writer beans the values in stepExecution are not correct. The readCount I get when I tried is 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you use a simple tasklet instead of using a chunk-oriented step. You could use an `ItemReader<SomeObject>` and an `ItemWriter<SomeObject>` that does the `someDataSendOperation`.

With that, you don't need to iterate over the list yourself and you will get the counts you are looking for.